# Oracle oracledb NPM module won't build with node-gyp and Windows

Tags: node.js, oracle, visual-studio, npm

I've been trying to get the Oracle client for Node.js, `oracledb`, built on Windows 7.  When I run `npm install oracledb` I see a large number of errors, such as:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'oci.h'
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'oratypes.h'
```

As well as error messages like `unrecognizable template declaration/definition` and `syntax error : 'using'`.

I've been trying to build the oracledb client mostly with Node.js 5.8.0, but I've tried with older versions as well with the same result.  My python version is 2.7.9.  I've installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Express, the newest available right now, as well as the Oracle InstantClient 12.1 (also current), but I still get pages of compiler errors from the `node-gyp` build process when running `npm install oracledb`.

This isn't the first NPM module I've had trouble building, and I've installed older versions of Visual Studio in the past (2010, 2012, 2013).  I've tried uninstalling them as well, but I'm not convinced they actually uninstalled fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bulk of the instructions that need to be followed for building `oracledb` for Node.js can [be found here](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/INSTALL.md#instwin).  But I'll sum up the key points as well as point out the extra bit of knowledge that made all the difference.

First you need to install Oracle InstantClient and SDK into the same folder.  It's simplest, perhaps, if you rename and move that folder so that it becomes `c:\oracle\instantclient`.  You can get the basic InstantClient and SDK [from Oracle's site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html).  Make sure that you download 64 bit versions if you are using 64 bit Node.js and 32 bit versions if you are using 32 bit Node.js.

If you didn't install the InstantClient into `c:\oracle\instantclient`, then you need this next step.  Add the following environment variables to your system:

```
set OCI_LIB_DIR=C:\my-path-to-instantclient-here\sdk\lib\msvc
set OCI_INC_DIR=C:\my-path-to-instantclient-here\sdk\include
```

The commands above could be pasted into a command prompt to temporarily set the values, but you'd have to go into Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables to create new variables **with the correct paths** that match your installation to make the changes permanent.

Make sure that your Node.js, the Oracle InstantClient folder, and Python are all in your system's `PATH` environment variable.

Next download and install [Visual Studio Express 2015 for Desktop](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx).

Ensure that it, too, is in your `PATH`.

**Here is the trick that saved me:**  If you have multiple versions of Visual Studio set, you need to tell `node-gyp` which one to use (in this case, 2015).  To do that you have options.

1) You could create an environment variable named `GYP_MSVS_VERSION` and set its value to `2015`.

2) You could also pass the 2015 value on the `NPM` command line like this:

```
npm install oracledb --save --msvs_version=2015
```

Or you could, and I find this to be the best method, set the version of Visual Studio that `node-gyp` should use globally with the following command:

```
npm config set msvs_version 2015 --global
```

You can then do a `npm config list` to verify that the config change took hold.

At that point you should be able to do a regular old `npm install --save oracledb` command and have it install and build in whichever project you like.  Other compiled NPM modules should also build well now, too.